# C++ Stuck with vector iterators incompatible, can't find why

Tags: c++, vector

Whenever I try to interate through a std::vector, It will keep telling me: **vector iterators incompatible**

This is the function that's throwing me the crash:

```
// These 2 typedefs are declared in structs.h
typedef std::pair<uint32_t, Object*> PlayerContainerPair;
typedef std::vector<PlayerContainerPair> PlayerContainers;

// This is a variable from Player class in player.h
PlayerContainers m_containers;

// Definition of the function found in player.cpp
int32_t Player::GetContainerId(Object* container)
{
    for (PlayerContainers::const_iterator cl = m_containers.begin(); cl != m_containers.end(); ++cl){
        if (cl->second == container)
            return static_cast<int32_t>(cl->first);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Basically whenever I try to loop through the vector it will keep crashing my application, I have checked the Object and it is an object class, it's not null.

What else is causing this error?

Comment: `c1` is `const_iterator`, but `m_containers.end()` is plain `iterator`. Use `cbegin()` and `cend()` instead, or else declare `c1` as just `iterator`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik tried using iterator only, same result.

Comment: What's "*iterator only*"? You clearly have an error pointed by Igor. Correct it and make a minimal compilable example.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Standard iterators can convert to (but not from) and be compared with their const_iterator counterparts. Besides, this is a runtime error.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Tried using a very minimal example, and I cannot reproduce this. I have literally no idea what is going on lol, this is the minimal example: http://pastebin.com/83AM6p9H What can I do to know the cause if none of the objects are null in the debugger of VS2013.

Comment: compiling in Release mode, the application will not crash entirely.

Comment: Sounds like there could be memory corruption somewhere, especially if it cannot be easily reproduced in a minimlal example. Maybe something writes over `m_containers`.

Comment: This usually happens because you are comparing iterators from two different containers. And I often see it when people return a container from a function by value. For example, something like this: http://ideone.com/eeUTYE

Comment: btw, the reason it's not crashing in release mode is because in release mode, checked iterators are disabled. The bug is still there, somewhere in your code, but you're just getting unlucky that it's not crashing.

Comment: The author posted an MCVE here:  pastebin.com/83AM6p9H. I tried it in VS2015 and it doesn't crash in debug or release; however, he noted he is using 2013 and that for him it only crashes in debug, which suggests that it is an MSVC STL issue (the debug version does all kinds of additional checks). It is probably rejecting, as others have pointed out, the conversion from a non-const iterator to a const iterator. I realize that it *shouldn't*, but he can probably fix it by saying `PlayerContainers::const_iterator cl = m_containers.cbegin(); cl != m_containers.cend(); ++cl`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I understand, but m_containers is a private variable from the **Player** class which i'm calling the function from.

Comment: @ksfone: Doubtful. I've never seen VC have a problem with that. Also, he didn't post an MVCE. He was missing the V, i.e. it doesn't reproduce the problem, even for him.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley According to him it reproduced the problem in /debug/ in vs2013. I don't have vs2013 to test with, only 2015.

Comment: @kfsone: I don't see anywhere that he said that, except in reference to his original code. About his minimal example (the one you linked), he said this: *"Tried using a very minimal example, and I cannot reproduce this. I have literally no idea what is going on lol, this is the minimal example"*

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the problems reproduces in debug mode vs2013 but not in release mode. A guy said I'm just unlucky the bug doesn't reproduce in release mode, but tried many times unsuccessfully.

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro: You mean your original code, that you first asked the question about? Or do you mean this: http://pastebin.com/83AM6p9H

Comment: @BenjaminLindley my original code, I wonder that if I use MingW or a GNU Compiler instead of MSVC one will I have the same result?

Comment: @RaúlSanpedro: If you do try it, use the `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` option to turn on checked iterators.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
for (auto cl = m_containers.begin(); cl != m_containers.end(); ++cl){
    if (cl->second == container)
        return static_cast<int32_t>(cl->first);
}
```

should fix your problem

EDIT Removed the & as suggested below

A minimal example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

struct Object {};

// These 2 typedefs are declared in structs.h
typedef std::pair<uint32_t, Object*> PlayerContainerPair;
typedef std::vector<PlayerContainerPair> PlayerContainers;

// This is a variable from Player class in player.h
PlayerContainers m_containers;

// Definition of the function found in player.cpp
int32_t GetContainerId(Object* container)
{

    for (auto cl = m_containers.begin(); cl != m_containers.end(); ++cl){
        if (cl->second == container)
            return static_cast<int32_t>(cl->first);
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    Object* o = new Object;
    m_containers.push_back(PlayerContainerPair(1, o));
    std::cout << GetContainerId(o);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and runs as expected, with vs2013

Comment: @BaummitAugen It does compile. It doesn't fixes the problem, note I'm debugging with VS2013.

Comment: Why do you think this would fix the problem?

Comment: I guessed the incompatible const iterator was the problem, gimme a sec

Comment: @BaummitAugen Or add one more and make it `auto&&`, but that would be pointless here.

Comment: Using a minimal example ref here: http://pastebin.com/83AM6p9H compiles just fine, however, with the full project on debug mode the app will just crash whenever that function is called, but if it's in release mode, nothing will happen and it will work just fine.

Comment: I am guessing, your problem is not this function